# Updating a static variable when extending a Python class

Tags: python, dictionary, extending-classes

I am writing an extension to a library and I would like to register my new function with a dictionary of function pointers in the base class. My understanding is that the dictionary, since it is at the uppermost scope within a class, is static and should be update-able. However, when I try to `update()` the dictionary with the new function in the extended class it tells me that it is undefined. The following minimal example reproduces the error:

```py
def somefunction1(v):
    return v

def somefunction2(v):
    return v

class SomeClass(object):
    dictionary = {'a':somefunction1}

class SomeExtensionClass(SomeClass):
    dictionary.update({'b':somefunction2})
```

Running it gives the following error

```
 9 
 10 class SomeExtensionClass(SomeClass):
 ---> 11         dictionary.update({'b':somefunction2})

NameError: name 'dictionary' is not defined
```

Since I cannot (reasonably) modify the original `SomeClass` is there any way around this?

**Edit: The desired result is that `SomeExtensionClass` will have `dictionary={'a':somefunction1, 'b':somefunction2}`**

Comment: Even if you could do `dictionary.update({'b':somefunction2})`, you would be modifying `SomeClass`. Specifically, `SomeClass.dictionary` would now have an entry for `'b'`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. I updated the original question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify `SomeClass.dictionary`, just refer to it as `SomeClass.dictionary`:

```
SomeClass.dictionary.update(whatever)
```

Variable lookup within a `class` statement doesn't look through the superclasses' attributes.

If you want a new dictionary, so `SomeExtensionClass.dictionary` is different from `SomeClass.dictionary`, you'll want to copy the original and update the copy:

```
class SomeExtensionClass(SomeClass):
    dictionary = SomeClass.dictionary.copy()
    dictionary.update(whatever)
```

Comment: This will also update the base class dictionary. That seems like it would be undesired behaviour.

Comment: @ebarr: It's the behavior the OP says he wants. There may be a good reason; we don't entirely know what's going on.

Comment: Looks like I misread the question. I've deleted my answer as without the copy it is essentially the same as this.

Comment: @user2357112 apparently I didn't know either. Is it possible to create a `SomeExtensionClass` dictionary? Otus' method gives me error a NameError. I'm updating the original question. Apologies.

Comment: @Higany: Looks like otus's comment should have cleared up that issue by now. The only case where class scope is checked for variable lookup is for statements written directly in class scope. Within a method, you have to use attribute references like `self.dictionary` or `SomeExtensionClass.dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasonable ways to give SomeExtensionClass an updated dictionary:

1. Update the original dictionary by referring to `SomeClass.dictionary`.
2. Define a second `dictionary` variable for the derived class.

You can do the second like this:

```
class SomeExtensionClass(SomeClass):
    dictionary = dict(SomeClass.dictionary, b=somefunction2)
```

Which you should choose depends on who uses the dictionary and for what. If a SomeClass method uses the variable like this:

```
def foo(self):
    a = self.dictionary['a']()
```

The method will use the SomeExtensionClass dictionary for SomeExtensionClass objects. If OTOH it does:

```
def foo(self):
    a = SomeClass.dictionary['a']()
```

It will always use the dictionary defined in SomeClass.

Comment: "You can't write general statements in class scope" - it's not clear what you mean by this. What's a "general statement"? You can write most kinds of statements in class scope.

Comment: @otus `class SomeExtensionClass(SomeClass):
 dictionary = dict(SomeClass.dictionary, b=somefunction2)

 def prints(self):
  print(dictionary)

a = SomeExtensionClass()
a.prints()` Gives me a `NameError: global name 'dictionary' is not defined` error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Higany, when referring to class variables you need to refer either through a class (`SomeExtensionClass.dictionary`) or an instance (`self.dictionary`). For the difference, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python). In your `prints` example you probably want `self.dictionary`.